# Color Category Tabs Gone in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, winforms

In Visual Studio 2012, there were color category tabs for properties like BackColor, ForeColor, etc in Windows Forms projects.  I opened up a new project today and those properties have the colors in alphabetical order without the tabs.  Does anybody know how to get those tabs back?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've clicked the Properties sort mode to *Alphabetical*:

[image: Alphabetical Sort]

When what you wanted was *Categorized*:

[image: Categorized Sort]